# Android-After rebooting, launching one application from another application does not open the app

Tags: android, root, android-launcher

I am experiencing an issue with opening an app on Android 13. When I use the following code to launch another application, it works fine after rebooting the tablet.

```
            val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
            intent.putExtra("fromIntent", true)
            intent.setPackage("com.example.myapp")
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            intent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICE_TYPE_ID, deviceType)
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.myapp", "com.example.myapp.MainActivity")
            startActivity(intent)
            finishAffinity()
```

However, if I use a different code to launch another application, it doesn't work after a tablet reboot. I am expecting the below code working.

```
        val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myapp")
        if (intent != null) {
            intent.putExtra("fromIntent", true)
            intent.setPackage("com.example.myapp")
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            intent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICE_TYPE_ID, deviceType)
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
            intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.myapp", "com.example.myapp.MainActivity")
            startActivity(intent)
            finishAffinity()
        } else {
            Utils.showErrorLog(TAG, "Null Intent")
        }
```

In normal cases, it's working fine. However, the issue was faced after restarting the tablet. Can you please provide a solution why the above code is not working?

Comment: You did not tell what all this has to to with rebooting. What happens if you dont reboot? And can you execute code if you did not -re-boot?

Comment: Or: if code does not work after reboot then when does it do the job?

Comment: And what happens instead if your code 'does not work'?

Comment: Further i wonder which Android version on used device.

Comment: @blackapps I have a screen with a button that, on clicking that button, opens another application. Initially, everything works well - the second app opens as expected. 

However, after installing, opening, killing, and reopening the app, it functions correctly. 

The problem arises after a reboot, where my first application, a kiosk application with root access, automatically opens. Strangely, when I click the button to open the second app, the first application opens again instead of the intended second application. If I exist from the kiosk app and again open then it works fine.

Comment: 29 is my target version and I am running application in android 13 lenovo tablet